# PV of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^n~ e^{-ax^2} dx}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)},~ (n=0,1,2,3,...)$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

$$\tag{1} I_n = PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{x^n ~e^{-ax^2} dx}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)},~ (n=0,1,2,3,...)~\text{with}~a>0~\text{and}~  x_1~x_2 \in \mathbb{R},$$
Is the principal value of $I_1$ calculable?

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are on the path of integration on the real axis, I was thinking of indenting the contour, passing over them clockwise picking up

$$\tag{2}-\pi i[\mathrm{Res}(f,x_1)+\mathrm{Res}(f,x_2)]$$

where $f$ is the integrand. To use the residue theorem I close the contour along a semi circle, $\Gamma_\infty$, in the upper half plane. But I suspect that the contribution of the integral 
$$\tag{3}\int_{\Gamma_\infty} dz ~f(z)$$ is non-zero. Since on $\Gamma_\infty$ we have $z = Re^{i\theta}$.

Assuming this is correct, one finds
$$\tag{4}
I_n = i\pi [\mathrm{Res}(f,x_1)+\mathrm{Res}(f,x_2)]-\int_{\Gamma_\infty} dz ~f(z).
$$
Does all this make sense? And is there a simple estimate/computation of (3) above?

(Note: Mathematica can do the integral (1) in terms of incomplete Gamma functions, but the total expression seems to be indeterminate at integer values of $n$.)

Comment: Not the Residue, it should be semi-circles around that two poles, with angle goes from $\pi$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

## Hint:

> \begin{align}
> &\mbox{With}\ \pars{~a > 0\,;\ x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{and}\
> n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}~}, \,\,\,\mbox{note that}
> \\
> & I_{n} =
> \mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{n}\expo{-ax^{2}}
> \over \pars{x - x_{1}}\pars{x - x_{2}}}\,\dd x =
> {1 \over x_{2} - x_{1}}\,\sum_{k = 1}^{2}\pars{-1}^{k}\,
> \bbox[#fee,5px]{\ds{\mrm{P.V.}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{n}\expo{-ax^{2}}
> \over x - x_{k}}\,\dd x}}\label{1}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#fee,5px]{\ds{\mrm{P.V.}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{n}\expo{-ax^{2}}
\over x - x_{k}}\,\dd x}} =
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{%
\pars{x + x_{k}}^{n}\expo{\large -a\pars{x + x_{k}}^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\pars{x + x_{k}}^{n}\expo{\large -a\pars{x + x_{k}}^{2}} -
\pars{-x + x_{k}}^{n}\expo{\large -a\pars{-x + x_{k}}^{2}}\over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{%
\pars{x + x_{k}}^{n}\expo{\large -a\pars{x + x_{k}}^{2}} -
\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{x - x_{k}}^{n}\expo{\large -a\pars{x - x_{k}}^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

Comment: The pv integral in red, if one indent the contour over the pole at $x_k$, it looks finite and the epsilon semi circle goes to zero (like $\epsilon ^n$). While the final version not so much as it looks like $ 1/\epsilon  $

Comment: Also at large radi $R$ it goes like $e^{-R^2}$ so it should die off fast enough right?

Comment: @JustAsk Yes, that's true. The exponential term provides the convergence as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure that the arc (at infinity) contribution is so trivial. On the arc, the Gaussian $e^{-z^2}$ becomes proportional to $e^{-i R^2 \sin(2\phi)}$ also. For instance, $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0 }\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1+i \epsilon} = -\frac{\pi  (erfi(1)+i)}{e}$ while jumping over the pole ($-i \pi \mathrm{Res}(x=1-i \epsilon)$) and taking the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ limit gives $-\frac{i \pi }{e}$. So something's missing. And I suspect the rest comes from the arc at infinity. Any thoughts? Note: Erfi(z)  = erf(i z)/i

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749560/110467

Comment: @JustAsk I never talk about 'closing the contour'. My point (in my previous comment) was that the 'decaying' exponential is enough to assure the integrals convergence as they are written in my above answer. Otherwise, your comment is correct.