# Arc contribution in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}z \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Consider an improper integral with a pole on the integration contour at say $z=1$,

$$
 \tag{1} I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}z\ \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-1+i\epsilon},~~~~~\epsilon>0. 
$$
Let $$f(z) = \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-1+i\epsilon}$$
then 
$$
\sum_{residues~inside~\Gamma} = 0 = \oint_\Gamma f(z) = I+\left(\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}+\int_{\Gamma_\infty} \right) f(z), 
$$
where the total contour is $\Gamma\equiv (-R,R)+\Gamma_\epsilon+\Gamma_\infty$ with $R\rightarrow \infty$.

Thus 
$$
 I = - \left(\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}+\int_{\Gamma_\infty} \right) f(z). 
$$
The contour $\Gamma_\epsilon$ is a semicircle centered about $z = 1$ of radius $\epsilon$. Its contribution is given by 
$$
\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon} \mathrm{d}z ~f(z) = i (\theta_2-\theta_1)~ \mathrm{Res}(f;z=1) = \frac{-i\pi}{e}. 
$$

Evaluating $(1)$ in Mathematica and taking the $\epsilon\rightarrow 0 $ limit gives 
$$
I = e^{(\epsilon +i)^2} \left(-\pi  \text{erfi}(1-i \epsilon )+\log (-1+i \epsilon )+\log
   \left(\frac{i}{\epsilon +i}\right)-2 i \pi \right)
\\
\longrightarrow 
-\frac{\pi  (\text{erfi}(1)+i)}{e}~~~(\text{as}~ \epsilon \rightarrow 0). 
$$

Thus apparently, 
$$ \tag{2}
\int_{\Gamma_\infty} \mathrm{d}z \, f(z) = \frac{2\pi i}{e}+\frac{\mathrm{erfi}(1)}{e}. 
$$

Can anyone derive this contribution from the semicircle at infinity? I.e. is $(2)$ correct and how about generalizations of $(1)$ to integrals of the form

$$\tag{3}
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}z\ \frac{z^n e^{-z^2}}{(z-a+i\epsilon)(z-b-i\epsilon)},~~~~~\epsilon>0,a,b\in\mathbb{R},n\in \mathbb{N}. 
$$

---

Note, erfi is defined as
$\mathrm{erfi}(z) \equiv \mathrm{erf}(iz)/i$ with the familiar error function.

Comment: Why do you have $\Gamma_\epsilon$?  There's no pole on or above the real axis. Also, even if there were, you should be shrinking the radius of that component towards that pole.

Comment: I was thinking that for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ the pole is at $z=1$ i.e. on the real axis hence we must indent the contour over it.

Comment: This happens for no nonzero $\epsilon$, so no deflection is needed.

Comment: Finite you mean $\epsilon>0$? But I do take the zero limit in the above formulas.

Comment: The order that you take limits matters.  There is a sequence of positive $\epsilon_i$s, approaching $0$, but your integral needs no accommodation for any of them.

Comment: I have a bounty to give! Don't miss it!

Comment: I have to award the bounty (a matter of hours)! Do your best!;)

Answer (score 3):

To check your work: if you care about a fast solution, start with considering $I(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a(x^2-1)}}{x-1}\textrm{dx}$, where by differentiating with respect to $a$ and then integrating back, we're lead to $I(1)=-\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{e^a}{\sqrt{a}}\textrm{d}a=-\pi\operatorname{erfi}(1).$ Hence, we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1}\textrm{dx}=-\frac{\pi}{e}\operatorname{erfi}(1).$$

**Note**: the integrals above have a meaning only in the CPV sense as seen described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value.

**Literature:** related to **Faddeeva function** (it's sometimes referred to as the plasma dispersion function) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeeva_function.

Comment: Let's forget about the $i\epsilon$ for a minute. I compute $PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1} = -\pi e^{-1}\mathrm{erfi}(1) = + i \pi e^{-1} \mathrm{erf}(i)$. Indenting over the pole at $x=1$ gives $-i\pi \mathrm{Res}(f,1) = -i\pi e^{-1}$. Clearly these two don't cancel to yield zero as the closed loop integrals contains no poles, the total contribution should be zero. The only contribution left is that from the arc at infinity.

Comment: @JustAsk I'm investigating the point.

Comment: @JustAsk You're perfectly right. My investigations shows the contribution comes from the sum of the integrals $\int_{\Gamma_\infty, \theta \in [\pi/4,\pi/2]}$ and $\int_{\Gamma_\infty \theta \in [\pi/2,3\pi/4]}$ on the big arc. Again, both integrals must be viewed in terms of PVC, since separately both blow up to $\infty$. The reamining two integrals on the big arc vanish through the ML inequality.

Comment: OK it would be nice if you'd write it up as an answer.

Comment: @JustAsk What's curious to me is that you're fine with getting $PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1}$ by real methods. I initially thought you wanted to compute everything by contour integration. Not sure why you would want to know what's happening on the big arc *in this case*.

Comment: @JustAsk In case you're fine with using the PV obained by real methods, the problem is finalized, and I'm sure you can do it on your own.

Comment: Well actually I am interested in doing the integral with residues. Or more generally I want to regulate the integrals defined in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2750032/110467 
....

I realize that $e^{-z^2}$ in the numerator complicates things. But there should be some other simple function $f(z)$ (see link) that yields the contr. from the arc at infinity zero, well apart from the usual Jordan's lemma exp.

Comment: What's worrisome about doing the integral with real methods, using $$f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-a(z^2-1)}}{z-1}\,\mathrm{d}z$$ is that that integral does not converge. Using principal value for $f$ instead of the integral above, and filling in some details, we *then* get that $$\begin{align}f'(a) &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(z^2-1)}(z+1)\,\mathrm{d}z\\ &=e^a\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-az^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\\ &=\sqrt{\frac\pi a}\,e^a\end{align}$$ Leaving out all mention of the principal value is dangerous.

Comment: @robjohn Since the OP didn't use in the main question any word about PV I assumed he/she knows perfectly we talk about the Cauchy principal value and I didn't use the notation either. I agree that using the notation is best. The integrals above have a meaning only in the CPV sense.

Comment: @robjohn Both the integral on the real line and the one on the big arc must be viewed in the CPV sense.

Answer (score 3):

Near the top of the arc, the integrand blows up exponentially. I would avoid using that arc.

---

**Real Method**

By substituting $z\mapsto-z$, we get
$$
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-1}\mathrm{d}z
=-\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z+1}\mathrm{d}z\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2-1}e^{-2z}}{z}\mathrm{d}z
&=-\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2-1}e^{2z}}{z}\mathrm{d}z\tag2\\
&=-\frac1e\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\frac{\sinh(2z)}z\,\mathrm{d}z\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: substitute $z\mapsto z+1$ on the left and $z\mapsto z-1$ on the right of $(1)$
$(3)$: average the right and left of $(2)$

Setting
$$
f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\frac{\sinh(az)}z\,\mathrm{d}z\tag4
$$
we have $f(0)=0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
f'(a)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\cosh(az)\,\mathrm{d}z\tag5\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}e^{az}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag6\\
&=e^{a^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag7\\[3pt]
&=\sqrt\pi\,e^{a^2/4}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(5)$: take the derivative under the integral
$(6)$: $\cosh(ax)$ is the even part of $e^{ax}$
$(7)$: substitute $z\mapsto z+a/2$
$(8)$: evaluate the integral

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-1}\mathrm{d}z
&=-\frac1e\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2}\frac{\sinh(2z)}z\,\mathrm{d}z\tag9\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt\pi}e\int_0^2e^{a^2/4}\,\mathrm{d}a\tag{10}\\
&=-\frac{2\sqrt\pi}e\int_0^1e^{a^2}\,\mathrm{d}a\tag{11}\\[3pt]
&=-\frac\pi{e}\,\operatorname{erfi}(1)\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{0}(9)$: apply $(3)$
$(10)$: apply $(8)$
$(11)$: substitute $a\mapsto2a$
$(12)$: evaluate the integral

---

**A Cleaner, But Still Real, Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{13}\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{14}\\
&=\left.\frac1e\,\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-a(x^2-1)}}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right]_{a=1}\tag{15}\\
&=\frac1e\,\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac1e\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x^2-1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}a\tag{16}\\
&=0-\frac1e\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac\pi a}\,e^a\,\mathrm{d}a\tag{17}\\
&=-\frac{2\sqrt\pi}e\int_0^1e^{a^2}\,\mathrm{d}a\tag{18}\\
&=-\frac{2\sqrt\pi}e\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\,\operatorname{erfi}(1)\tag{19}\\[6pt]
&=-\frac\pi e\,\operatorname{erfi}(1)\tag{20}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(13)$: substitute $x\mapsto-x$
$(14)$: average the left and right sides of $(13)$
$(15)$: set up for differentiation under the integral
$(16)$: write as the integral of the derivative under the integral
$(17)$: the PV can be evaluated using a simple contour integration
$\phantom{(17)\text{:}}$ evaluate the inner integral on the right
$(18)$: substitute $a\mapsto a^2$
$(19)$: evaluate the integral
$(20)$: simplify

which agrees with $(12)$.

Comment: It would be nice finding a way of getting the value of the integral over the real line by contour integration exclusively.

Comment: @Waiting: I agree, but I don't think it is going to use the big arc as [that way madness lies](https://www.owleyes.org/text/king-lear/read/act-iii-scene-iv/root-71873-6/80997-6#root-71873-4-4). SInce erfi is involved, it might be difficult to find a significantly different path.

Comment: King Lear? Interesting that my requirements make you think of the Shakespeare literature (due to the *development* of things on the big arc). :-)

Comment: Intuition tells me there *must* be a way (at least) by contour integration.

Comment: I have to award the bounty soon. Couldn't you find yet a solution by contour integration exclusively?

Comment: @Waiting: I tried again for quite some time yesterday to try finding a contour integration solution for this problem, but was unable. Since you've awarded the bounty to me, I will continue looking and hopefully find a way to earn it.

Comment: sure, no need to hurry with that. I think this is an interesting question whose answer might open the gate for solutions to more difficult questions similar to this one. After all, I'm glad I could give you the bounty. :-) (some questions simply need more thinking time)

Comment: I'll also return to this one in the future if time allows :)

Answer (score 0):

The contribution from the (superfluous) deformation of the segment on $[0,2]$ to a semicircle is cancelled by other parts of the integral along the real axis.  This deformation crosses no poles, so the path integral along $\Gamma_\epsilon + [0,2]$ is zero.

So what's going on?  In your expression
$$ I+\left(\int_{\Gamma_\epsilon}+\int_{\Gamma_\infty} \right) f(z) \text{,} $$
you have two paths from $0$ to $2$.  One runs along the real axis and is contributed by $I$.  The other runs along $\Gamma_\epsilon$.  It should come as no surprise that this contribution is overcounted in the result you have.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-z^{2}} \over z - 1}\,\dd z & =
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{z + 1}^{2}} \over z}\,\dd z =
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\pars{z + 1}^{2}} - \expo{-\pars{z - 1}^{2}} \over z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\pars{z + \sigma}^{2}}\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-zx}\dd x}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{z^{2} + 2\sigma z + 1 + xz}}\,\dd z\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\bracks{z + \sigma + {x \over 2}}^{2} - 1 + \sigma^{2} + \sigma x + {x^{2} \over 4}}\,\dd z\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{\sigma x + {x^{2} \over 4}}\int_{\sigma + x/2}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-z^{2}}\,\dd z\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-z^{2}}
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{0}^{2z - 2\sigma}
\exp\pars{{1 \over 4}\braces{\bracks{x + 2\sigma}^{\, 2} - 4\sigma^{2}}}
\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-z^{2}}
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{2\sigma}^{2z}\exp\pars{x^{2} \over 4}
\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
2\expo{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-z^{2}}
\sum_{\sigma = \pm 1}\sigma\int_{\sigma}^{z}\exp\pars{x^{2}}
\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
-2\expo{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-z^{2}}
\bracks{\int_{-1}^{z}\exp\pars{x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\int_{1}^{z}\exp\pars{x^{2}}\,\dd x}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
-2\expo{-1}\ \overbrace{\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-z^{2}}\dd z}}
^{\ds{\root{\pi} \over 2}}\
\overbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\pars{x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ x = -\ic t}}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\expo{-1}\root{\pi}\int_{0}^{\ic}\exp\pars{-t^{2}}\pars{-\ic}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\ic\pi\expo{-1}
\bracks{{2 \over \root{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\ic}\exp\pars{-t^{2}}\dd t} =
\bbx{\ic\pi\expo{-1}\mrm{erf}\pars{\ic}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\,\mrm{erf}\pars{\ic} = \ic\,\mrm{erfi}\pars{1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=-pv.\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x-1}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\Gamma (\frac{1-2n}{2})\\
\\
\\
=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{2^n.\sqrt{\pi }}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }(2m-1)}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{2^n\sqrt{\pi }}{\frac{2^n.\Gamma (n+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi }}}\\
\\
\\
\therefore I=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{\pi }{\Gamma (n+\frac{1}{2})}=-\sqrt{\pi }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma (n).\Gamma (\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma (n)\Gamma (n+\frac{1}{2})}\\
\\
\\
=-\sqrt{\pi }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{x}(n-1)!}dx\\
\\
\\
\therefore I=-\frac{\pi }{e}.ierf(i)=\frac{\pi }{e}erfi(1$$