# Regulating divergent integrals in the complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

If I want to do the integrals $I_n$ with residue techniques, what are appropriate functions $f(x)$ to regulate integrals of the form 
$$
I_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^n}{(x-a)(x-b)}\times f(x),~~~~a,b\in\mathbb{R}. 
$$
If I choose a Gaussian $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, then the contribution from the arc at infinity goes like 
$$
e^{-R^2\cos{2\phi}}e^{-iR^2\sin{2\phi}}, ~~~~\phi\in(0,\pi) 
$$
which is not zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$ because of the $e^{-iR^2\sin{2\phi}}$.

So are there any nice functions $f(x)$ that yields zero contribution from the arc at infinity and at the same time make $I_n$ we defined?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}R^2 \sin 2 \phi} |
    &=  1  \text{.}  \\
\end{align*}
The value is confined to a disk.  If the radius of the disk shrinks to zero, the phase doesn't matter.

Comment: But $R\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @JustAsk : And $\mathrm{e}^{-R^2} \rightarrow 0$.  What's the phase of $0$?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749560/110467 where I've explained the problem of contribution from the arc at infinity for a specific case.

Comment: @JustAsk : There you've deformed the path and asked how the infinite arc accounts for the deformation.  It doesn't.  The deformation is homologous to the undeformed line segment and its contribution is cancelled by the rest of the real axis integral.